# React Navigation TabBarIcon not appearing

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I can't get a `TabBarIcon` to appear in my `TabNavigator.` I've read a bunch of posts from people with a similar issue, but their solutions don't work for me. I'd really just like to be able to have a PNG image component for each `TabBarIcon` but it just won't appear.

```
const Tabs = TabNavigator({
    Feed: {
      screen: FeedPage,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel:"Feed",
        tabBarIcon: () => (<Image source={require('./Resources/Images/TabBar Icons_Feed.png')} style={{height: 10, width: 10}} />)
      }
    },
    Me: {
      screen: MePage,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel:"Me",
      }
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Me',
    tabBarOptions: {
      showIcon: true,
      showLabel: true
    }
  }
);

const RootStack = StackNavigator(
  {
    //All Tabs
    Tabs: {
      screen: Tabs,
    },
    //Other Pages
    Signup: {
      screen: SignupPage,
    },
    ProfilePicUploader: {
      screen: ProfilePicUploaderPage,
    },
    Login: {
      screen: LoginPage,
    },
    User: {
      screen: UserPage,
    },
    EasterEgg: {
      screen: EasterEggPage,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Tabs',
    headerMode: 'none'
  }
);

export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <RootStack/>
    );
  }
}
```

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: It might just be that the image is being clipped. Can you confirm that the image shows in ordinary circumstances, like just rendered on a page? Try using `resizeMode: contain` in the image style.

Comment: @JulianK The image shows up otherwise, and other images don't work either when put in its place. `resizeMode: contain` doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

You just need make sure that your file doesn't have whitespace name. So change `TabBar Icons_Feed.png` to `TabBar_Icons_Feed.png`. Because `android` or `ios` will find name like `/xxxx/Resources/Images/TabBar%20Icons_Feed.png`. This actually the `packager` does the job.  See [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#static-image-resources):

> The image name is resolved the same way JS modules are resolved. In
>   the example above, the `packager` will look for `my-icon.png` in the same
>   folder as the component that requires it. Also, if you have
>   `my-icon.ios.png` and `my-icon.android.png`, the packager will pick the
>   correct file for the platform.

---

#### Check Valid/Correct Path File

if you see `.expo/packager-info.json`:

```
{
  "expoServerPort": 19000,
  "packagerPort": 19001,
  "packagerPid": 84703
}
```

as you see the port `packager` is `19001`, then you can access your file by `http://127.0.0.1:19001/Resources/Images/TabBar Icons_Feed.png` (make sure you already running app) in browser. You can make sure all path file is correct.

---

#### Permit on Android

Also, if you are using `expo` for development, make sure you set permission to write drawer for android ([source](https://lastpass.com/support.php?cmd=showfaq&id=9932)).

[image]

---

#### Best Practice

I usually use `import` image like this:

```
import Icon_Feed from './Resources/Images/TabBarIcons_Feed.png';

...

tabBarIcon: () => (
    <Image
        source={Icon_Feed}
        style={styles.stretch}
        />
)
```

It works and more readable.

Answer (score 3):

I have setup a smallest possible example to show image on tabs instead of icons have a look on [**this expo snack**](https://snack.expo.io/@shhzdmrz/showing-image-on-tab-navigator). Don't use `resizeMode` or `spaces` in the image file name as you are using `TabBar Icons_Feed.png`. Just import the file and use it with proper height and width,
e.g.

```
import Icon_Feed from './Resources/Images/TabBar_Icons_Feed.png';
```

and use it like this

```
tabBarIcon: () => (
    <Image source={Icon_Feed} style={{ height: 20, width: 20 }} />
),
```

**OR**

You can use require if you want to e.g.

```
tabBarIcon: () => (
    <Image source={require('./Resources/Images/TabBar_Icons_Feed.png')} style={{ height: 20, width: 20 }} />
),
```

[Read this image guide by react native official documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html) to get the possible ways to manage image and properly display it according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this one? This is my setup:

```
const PrimaryNav = TabNavigator({
  ['app/t1']: { screen: T1 },
  ['app/t2']: { screen: T2 },
}, {
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'app/t1',
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
      const { routeName } = navigation.state;
      if (routeName === 'app/t1') {
        return <Icon name="event-note" color={tintColor} />;
      } else if (routeName === 'app/t2') {
        return <Icon name="place" color={tintColor} />;
      }
      return null;
    },
  }),
  tabBarOptions: {
    showIcon: true,
    showLabel: false,
    activeTintColor: ApplicationStyles.screen.header.tintColor,
    inactiveTintColor: ApplicationStyles.screen.header.inactiveTintColor,
    style: {
      backgroundColor: ApplicationStyles.screen.header.backgroundColor,
    },
  }
})
```

`<Icon>` is the react-native-material-ui icon, but Image should work as well.

Comment: Damn. What you get in the place of icon? Blank?